# how to limit the number of selected items in a list in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: oneCardSelectinAnimation(),
    ));

class oneCardSelectinAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _oneCardSelectinAnimationState createState() =>
      _oneCardSelectinAnimationState();
}

class ListItem<T> {
  bool isSelected = false; //Selection property to highlight or not
  T data; //Data of the user
  ListItem(this.data); //Constructor to assign the data
}

class _oneCardSelectinAnimationState extends State<oneCardSelectinAnimation> {
  List<ListItem<String>> list;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    populateData();
  }

  void populateData() {
    list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 78; i++) list.add(ListItem<String>("item $i"));
  }

  int numberOfSelectedCards = 7;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("List Selection${numberOfSelectedCards}"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: _getListItemTile,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getListItemTile(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (list.any((item) => item.isSelected)) {
          setState(() {
            list[index].isSelected = !list[index].isSelected;
            print(list[index].isSelected);
            numberOfSelectedCards += 1;

            print(list[index].isSelected);
          });
        }
      },
      onLongPress: () {
        if (numberOfSelectedCards > 0) {
          setState(() {
            list[index].isSelected = true;
            numberOfSelectedCards -= 1;
          });
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
        color: list[index].isSelected ? Colors.red[100] : Colors.white,
        child: Image.asset(
          "images/scroll.png",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code what I wanted to do is limit the selected items to int numberOfSelectedCards = 7;

I want to select only seven of cards to be selected. 
I have tried to increase and decrease the numbersOfSelected cards under OnTaped and OnlongedPressed but it do not work correctly.

And if I navigate other page. I want to reset the page to 0 selected items(reset the page).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to use `tap` for selection of card and `longPress` for removing the selection as following 
Maintain two variables.

```dart
int maxSelectedCards = 7;
int currentSelectedCards = 0;
```

Modify the actions as following

```dart
onLongPress: () {
 if (currentSelectedCards > 0 && list[index].isSelected) {
   setState(() {
     list[index].isSelected = false;
     currentSelectedCards  -= 1;
   });
 }
},
```

```dart
onTap: () {
 if (currentSelectedCards < maxSelectedCards && !(list[index].isSelected) ) {
  setState(() {
    list[index].isSelected = true;
    currentSelectedCards += 1;
  });
}
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply Sanjay it worked perfectly. You are the best.

Comment: I think I have marked. I have ticked the green thick is it ok ?

Answer (score 2):

In `Dart 2.9.2` and `Flutter 1.20.4` you can do like this:

```
List<String> myList = new List();
myList = . . . //fill the list 
int startIndex = 0;
int endIndex = 3;
List<String> subList = new List();
subList = myList.sublist(startIndex, endIndex);
```